# Find and list the string of characters as per the requirement

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the data in Excel spanning 18K+ rows and 200+ columns. All the rows do not have an equal number of entries. I can fill those columns with 0.

The Representative data are presented below.
[image]

The result that I am looking for is as follows.The first column should have all the sequence of characters in decreasing/increasing order. Corresponding to this, the codes need to be mapped.

[image]

Is it possible to compile the data like this?

Regards

Anil

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, try the following:

1. Get unique sequences using the formula:

```
=UNIQUE(SORT(TOCOL(B2:G7,1)))
```

[image]

2. Filter codes based on the given sequence:

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(($B$2:$G$7=A11)*$A$2:$A$7),TOROW(FILTER(x,x<>0)))
```

[image]

3. Drag the formula down to fill the other cells

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Reddy. I have Office 365, and It really worked for me. I have to go through these formula and try for the original data.

Comment: I tried with a different set of data. The first code works fine for almost 20K rows, but, I got an error with even a small number for the 2nd code. Is it possible to discuss one-on-one?

Comment: @Anil What error did you get?

Comment: The 1st code works. In the given example, enter the formula in the 11th row, and the data is visible from the 11th row onwards. In my case, I entered the formula at the 18500th row and got "," and the data from the 18501 row onwards. In case of the 2nd formula, at B18500 cell got the error "#NUM"

Comment: #NUM means some numbers/values in the formula are wrong. "and got "," and the data from the 18501 row onwards", is showing a comma as results?

Comment: "," problem got resolved. This was due to one of the value. The #Num problem for the 1st formula  resolves when I include B to BE columns. But, when I include BF column, the problem appears. Rechecked all the 20K data points of BF column. Any suggestions? Is there any limit?

Comment: There must be some data on that column that is producing the error(s). Is the column's contents the same as the example. If possible, share the file and remove any sensible information.

Comment: it is difficult for me to share that file on a platform like this. Nevertheless, I can share it with you personally. Meanwhile, I am thinking of deleting this column to proceed further and relook at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147266/discussion-between-anil-and-reddy-lutonadio).